# How to copy everything from one directory to another using 'cp' command?

Tags: command-line, cp

I know that we can copy things from one directory to another using the command:

```
cp -Ri /path/one/* /path/two/*
```

Here: 
R = recursive
i = interactive

My questions:

1. Does this command copy everything? (Hidden folders & files, system folder & files, etc.)
2. If not, then what is the command? Or are there other softwares available for the job?

Answer (score 1):

1. no
2. do not specify the files:

   ```
   cp -Ri /path/one/ /path/two/
   ```

Comment: `cp -Ri /path/one/ /path/two/` Does this do the job? Or do I have to necessarily type the second and third commands?

Comment: Be very careful with the second set of commands. It will copy `/path` as well. Enable `dotglob` in bash instead.

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't think anyone here used `.*` . And `.*` expands to include `..`, which is where the problem lies.